# Case when in SQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm still learning about SQLPlus and I'm trying to populate a table called `DM_Businees` using the data from another table called `Business` (Oracle DB 12c if it helps).

In the `INSERT INTO` query I've put, among other things, this:

```
CASE
   WHEN BUSINESS.CATEGORIES LIKE '%Event%' THEN 'Event Planning'
   WHEN BUSINESS.CATEGORIES LIKE '%Financial%' THEN 'Financial Services'
   WHEN BUSINESS.CATEGORIES LIKE '%Home%' THEN 'Home Services'
   WHEN BUSINESS.CATEGORIES LIKE '%Professional%' THEN 'Professional Services'
   ELSE 'OTHER'
END
```

My goal here is to check the column `Categories` in `Business`: if it contains the word "Event" then write "Event Planning" in the column in `DM_Business`. The problem is that it doesn't work: it doesn't show any error, but every row is left empty.

I've tried the same thing, but with numbers instead (like 1 instead of "Event Planning", 2 instead of "Financial Services", 3 instead of "Home Services"...) and it works just fine (the column datatype is  `varchar2(200)`).

Can you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How is that possible? When I change the string in numbers, without touching anything else, it all works. How can I provide some sample data? (It's the YELP dataset if it helps)

Comment: What is the data type of the column in which data from `CASE` statement gets entered? Is it numeric?

Comment: @Jado: to provide test data you can **edit your own question** using the `edit` button just below the question text. Include the test data as formatted text - it's even better if you provide a table definition (i.e. `CREATE TABLE` statement) and a series of `INSERT` statements to populate the table(s). In this case, however, I suspect @zip's answer (below) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to test data, I would do somehing like this Jado:Make sure all is lower key

```
CASE
   WHEN lower(BUSINESS.CATEGORIES) LIKE '%event%' THEN 'Event Planning'
   WHEN lower(BUSINESS.CATEGORIES) LIKE 'financial%' THEN 'Financial Services'
   WHEN lower(BUSINESS.CATEGORIES) LIKE '%home%' THEN 'Home Services'
   WHEN lower(BUSINESS.CATEGORIES) LIKE '%professional%' THEN 'Professional Services'
   ELSE 'OTHER'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

What does the data in the columns look like?  Oracle is case-sensitive. You could try upper() or lower() to do the test. You also probably want to explicitly check for null

Something similar to:

```
CASE
    WHEN BUSINESS.CATEGORIES IS NULL THEN 'UNDEFINED'
    WHEN UPPER(BUSINESS.CATEGORIES) LIKE '%EVENT%' THEN 'Event Planning'
    WHEN UPPER(BUSINESS.CATEGORIES) LIKE 'FINANCIAL' THEN 'Financial Services' ...
```